# mysql queries which is the best

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know which way is better (faster) from those sql methods;

1st method:

```
public static function getlistusers($limit=88888888888888 ) {
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM users order by id desc limit 0,$limit";
$st = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
$list = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($st) ) {
$picss = new users( $row );
$list[] = $picss;
}   
return ( array ( "users" => $list) );
@mysql_free_result($st);
```

for print output i use

foreach() the array $users ;

---

2nd method

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM users order by id desc limit 0,$limit";
$st = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($st) ) {
extract($row);
return "Id: $id and The Name is : $name";
}   
@mysql_free_result($st);
}
```

===========

i want to know which is faster and safty for sql load.

Regards
Al3in

Comment: both are same queries where is the difference are you talking about the php code?

Comment: why `limit` is so much??

Comment: both is same, only php code diffrent not sql

Comment: For all questions of the type "Which query is faster" look at the Explain Plan. For all questions of the type "Which PHP code is faster" look at your Profiler results.

Comment: I think the votes are in.  While one may be better than the other, both are quite evil, so the best option is to replace both with a 3rd, better option.

Comment: Jeff Parker what is the 3rd option dear

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM users order by id desc limit 0,$limit";
$st = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($st) ) {
    extract($row);
    return "Id: $id and The Name is : $name";
}   
@mysql_free_result($st);
```

I doubt this approach will even work. Because, even though you limit it to 1 or a million, the loop will only run once because of `return "Id: $id and The Name is : $name";` . So if you're comparing this and the other method, the other method would obviously work better.

Unless you're assigning to an array instead of returning. In which case the second method has an unnecessary function call `extract` which puts two variables into the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Both are essentially the same. They execute the same query and retreive the results in the same way. The advantage of the first method is that it returns a list of data arrays that each represent a records in the database. All individual can be used any way you want. The second approach returns only a single string. The entire while loop is useless there.

So the second may be faster, because it only retrieves a single row, but from here that looks more like an error than like an actual implementation decision.